# Using moment.js, how to display the current date format for the user?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Given a text field, I want to have a suitable placeholder.  A typical placeholder will be something like: "mm/dd/yyyy".

However, I would like to use locale-aware dates using moment.js.

This means that I will be specifying "l" as the moment.js date format, howe do I determine the date format that moment.js will be using in this case?

The user will not understand what "l" means, so using this value in the placeholder text makes very little sense.

Specifically, I am hoping to be able to access something like moment's internal "defaultLongDateFormat". (Though that is merely a *default* - moment.js probably updates it or has some other mapping at runtime for locale-aware date formats - I would like to access that mapping.)

EDIT:

There are multiple downvotes (who aren't explaining why they're downvoting it).

I think this is because they arent' understanding the question, so here are some examples:

I want a function such that:
getFormat("l") -> "mm/dd/yyyy", or equivalent for the US locales.
getFormat("l") -> "dd/mm/yyyy", or equivalent, for the AU locales.

I do *not* want to format a given date, or to parse a given date - I merely want to determine it's user-friendly format given an arbitruary moment.js format, specifically, for 'l'.

Comment: To the downvoter: Why did you downvote this? It's a relevant question.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Are you asking to display the format of the current date or the date itself in a certain format?

Comment: @RobG: I was led to believe that moment.js defines these?  Ie, I specify the locale (eg, 'en'), and the format string (eg, 'L'), and then moment.js formats it?

Comment: @PrestonVanLoon: Neither.  I want the format string itself.  Ie, if moment("1234-12-12", "l") would have resulted in "12-12-1234", I want to have the resulting string "mm-dd-yyyy" instead.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand your question now. You want to print a hint for the format to use based on the "locale" that moment is using to interpret the string. Maybe you should just use an unambiguous date like 23/01/2015 so the user just follows that format. And I don't think place holders should be used for this, since they disappear once the user has entered something so they don't get the hint if they change the value.

Comment: @RobG: They shouldn't need the hint if they have a valid date there, surely, and if it follows their current locale, there should be minimal confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's exposed nicely, but if the browser has its language configured correctly you can do something like this:

```
var lang = navigator.languages ? navigator.languages : navigator.language;

moment().locale(lang).localeData()._longDateFormat['L']
```

Languages behave slightly differently depending on which browser you're using, so don't know how reliable this is.

Comment: That's perfect - works for both en_AU, and en_US.  I'll have to expect that this might be removed in a future revision, but this seems to be the best that can be done.

Comment: Have you tested it? Safari, Firefox and Ominweb all get it wrong for me. Chrome has a scatter gun approach with 3 different versions of en, but one of them was right.

Comment: Yes and like I said you have to have the language settings configured.

Comment: @RobG: I am actually dealing with an embedded chrome control in my application, so I have the luxury of being able to restrict my testing to a single browser.  I did test with 'en', 'en_AU', and 'en_US', though. :)

Comment: @Arafangion—IE 11 is the only one that gets it right for me.

Comment: @RobG: chromium embedded seemed to work, however I'll confess I didn't look at the nagivator's languages in detail: I can pass the language in from the host application and I seem to trust the host a bit more here.

Answer (score 5):

Follow up to Adam R's answer:

Seems to have been exposed by now:

`localeData.longDateFormat(dateFormat);`

returns the full format of abbreviated date-time formats LT, L, LL and so on

(source: http://momentjs.com/docs/)

Get the currently used locale data by `moment.localeData()`